# Working state restore

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-update

When the computer was rebooted by the Windows Update, the working state of the Microsoft software(like Word, Visual Studio, Outlook ....) will be restored when the computer after rebooting.
Does Windows provide these APIs to implement this feature? or How can I implement this feature in my C# Windows Form program? Thanks!

### Edit

If we open a Word file, and the computer is rebooted by Windows Update. And, the Word File will be reopen after the computer rebooted. How can I tell Windows that my program should be reopened after the computer reboot which caused by Windows Update?

Comment: Don't really understand what you mean. Could you explain more precisely what you want to happen, and when?

Comment: OK, when you say "reset" I guess you mean "reboot" or "restart". I'm afraid I don't know the answer to your question, but at least now I think I understand it.

Comment: Discussion here http://superuser.com/questions/94943/restoring-open-software-after-a-restart-event-in-windows , and someone recommends a program that costs $40. Someone else comments "I will add: Windows has something built in which it uses to reboot after certain updates are installed and a reboot is forced, and it will restore many/most of the windows to their original state. So, there is some OS level mechanism for this, not sure what it is nor how accessible it would be for us to use." So that confirms what you are saying.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will read it!